# Why Does Using the Python-YQL Module Change sys.path[0] to sys.path[1]?

Tags: python, directory, yql, sys

When I import the [python-yql](http://python-yql.org/) (Yahoo Query Language) module into my Python project, the string representing the local directory path from which the Python script is envoked, which is normally stored in `sys.path[0]` is changed to `sys.path[1]`. `sys.path[0]` gets replaced by the directory of what appears to be the location of the python-yql module. Is there a reason that `sys.path[0]` gets changed to `sys.path[1]` simply because the python-yql module is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `yql/__init.py` you'll find this line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
```

This is what inserts the yql path at the front of `sys.path`.

If the `yql` egg file is in your PYTHONPATH, then you can comment out or delete this `sys.path.insert` statement and the package should will still work.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Would commenting out sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')) make it so that if another machine was running the program and I referenced the local directory as sys.path[0], it would not function properly, since one can't assume that the other machine is also running with a modified __init__.py file? Would you recommend simply using sys.path[1] rather than commenting out the line in order to maintain compatibility?

Comment: You might want to ask the developer of python-yql to remove this line, since it is not necessary (I think) and is rather surprising behavior since [the docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path), "path[0]... is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter." Or, you could use `os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]` instead of `sys.path[0]`.

Comment: That seems like a valid point. What does __file__ represent in os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]?

Comment: `__file__` is a [predefined attribute](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) that Python sets to the pathname of the current file. (If you follow the link above, search for "`__file__`").

Comment: That is useful to know! Thank you for all the help!